# how do I debug on webpack with vs code on chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, npm, webpack

how do I debug on webpack with vs code on chrome browser? I am new to programming and the way i used to debug in browser doesn't work because webpack minifies it all to one line.
everything I found online seems irrelevant

Comment: Look into source maps. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Answer (score 0):

The sourcemaps generation should be enabled, e.g. on Angular you can enable them on angular.json, setting sourceMap = true

When it is running on chrome, you can found them on top -> webpack:// -> . (yes the last folder is a point/dot).

On the next link is an image with the folder structure of the sources tab in dev tools.

[Where to find the code with sourcemaps from webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU27a.png)